# How to set default value if the field is empty.-php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to set default value if the field is empty.

I have a text field with reset button with that, and also i want to set default value in that field.

If user wants to change the field value he can click on reset and enter new value and click on save.

If field is empty by default it should be default value.

on click of save its getting saved in database.

Here is my code

```
<td>
<input id="default_fromMail" name="default_fromMail" type="email" value="<?php echo isset($item['default_fromMail']) ? $item['default_fromMail'] : ''; ?>"
size="50" class="code" placeholder="<?php _e('', 'custom_table_example')?>"   /> 
<input  type="button" value="Reset" id="default_from_button" name="openLab5" />
</td>
```

As of now its getting saved into database.
But empty field is saved as it is(empty value)

I tried setting default value in table it self but still its not working.

Below is my db structure
[image]

i need xyz@gmail as default if the value is empty.

Answer (score 2):

In handler form code use this:

```
$email = (empty($_POST['default_fromMail']) ? 'xyz@gmail' : $_POST['default_fromMail'];
```

And then write `$email` to DB.

This variant better than set default value in DB column, 'cause if you want change default value, you need change only variable value against change table structure.

Answer (score 2):

you should check the value in the code that saves the field (form) value in the database. If this field is empty, you should pass it the default value.

```
$defaultMail = empty($_POST['default_fromMail']) ? 'xyz@gmail' : $_POST['default_fromMail'];
```

And then save the $defaultMail value to the database.